# Difference between two timestamps in hours

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I need to create a **DAX measure** to calculate the difference between two date time columns in hours

**Example**:

Column 1 (input): 2021-02-09 19:30:02

Column 2 (input): 2021-02-10 22:00:02

Difference in hours (output): 26.30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal representation of DATETIME is like in Excel, using the number of days elapsed. So to get the difference in hours is enough to compute the difference between the datetimes and multiply by 24 hours.

this is an example running on [dax.do](https://dax.do/JllxTBINHF3b0z/)

```
DEFINE
    TABLE T =
        DATATABLE (
            "DateTimeStart", DATETIME,
            "DateTimeEnd", DATETIME,
            {
                { "2021-02-09 19:30:02", "2021-02-10 22:00:02" }
            }
        )
EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS
(
    T,
    "Difference Hours", (T[DateTimeEnd] - T[DateTimeStart]) * 24
)
```

and this is the result

[image: the result]